# Preventing image theft on mobile devices

Tags: html

How do I prevent people from saving images from my site on their smart phones? Right click javascripts aren't working for mobile devices. On mobile devices you press and hold an image and select Save Image.

Comment: You'll never be able to completely prevent people from using your images. They can take screenshots, or they can even take a picture of their screen. But, if you really want to go through all the hassle, you might be able to figure something out with putting a transparent canvas on top of the image.

Comment: don't use images at all ;) really, you cant do what you are trying to

Comment: If i remember correctly, I've found using a div with css background prevents this. I'm no html expert so i don't know pros and cons to doing so :)

Comment: No matter what you do to prevent clicking, you can't possibly prevent any copying. Given that you send that picture to the user (and you must do that so he can see the picture), he will always have a way to save it.

Comment: The main goal here is to prevent the user from accessing Save Image options that are in plain sight. I know there are ways around these things, I'm not stupid, but fortunately, many people are (when it comes to using computers) and many will simply give up if the built in function is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something which **MAY** work.
Add another `<div>` over the image having `opacity:0`, this (atleast) won't allow the users to **save** the image. 
However, there isn't any perfect method to stop image theft as users can always take screenshots.

For Screenshots:

If you observe- while taking a screenshot in iOS devices (not sure about Android,..) the touch inputs being taken are cancelled out*. So, in order to avoid image theft (in iOS,..) you could just add a thumbnail and ask the users to hold it in order to view the HD (clear) image. Therefore, while the user takes the screen shot, because the touch inputs are cancelled, he would get only the thumbnail (probably of the size 16x16), which obviously wouldn't satisfy his/her needs. :)

*That's the reason you can't take a screenshot option being clicked (touched, here).

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The moment you put your images publicly online, the user is able to download it. In fact, the user *by definition* downloads it when they access your website, and they can grab it from cache or whatever.

Put a copyright/license on your site and hope for the best. That way you can take legal action against offending users.

No other method is effective at 100%, and this is the correct way to go.